# Is it possible to use cmake implement multi-core?

Tags: cmake, multicore

I am working on some cv algorithm code which is very computationally expensive. And the original code is not applied the multi-core or  multi-threads tech. Is it possible to use cmake to recompile it and make it able to use multi-core?

Kind Regards,

Patrick

Comment: `cmake` is just a build generator (e.g. it takes a generic makefile and generates a platform specific one). So, no. You didn't specify a language, so I'm assuming C. What you want is `openMP`, `MPI`, or splitting things up using `pthreads`. To get a better answer, you may want to post a representative sample of your code (aka an _MCVE_). Pick a "hot spot" or two. That is, sections of code that are intensive but you think could benefit from parallel _and_ have a probability of it (ie. look at the data dependencies in each step)

Comment: Thanks. I know that the pthreads can be used for multi-threads, but rewriting the source code is a big job for me. Actually the idea of using cmake to do the parallelism is inspired by the Computer Architecture coarse, that the compiler can do some parallel optimization.

Comment: Once again, `cmake` is just a  build tool. What you want is `openMP`. You just insert a special compiler directive above a loop. This tells `gcc` to parallelize it for you. It will do this for you by creating threads as needed [invisible to you]. There is _no_ source code rewrite at all. (e.g.) Above a `for` loop, just add `#pragma omp parallel for` and presto, it happens. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the `openMP`.

Comment: When I was looking around, I also came across `openCV`. If that's useful, I _think_ it plays well with `openMP`